# In Objective-C, is it possible to set default value for a class variable?

Tags: objective-c, default-value, class-variables

**Is there any way to set default values for class properties of a class?**
Like what we can do in Java, in the constructor of the class eg.-

```
MyClass(int a, String str){//constructor
  this.a = a;
  this.str = str;
  
  // I am loking for similar way in Obj-C as follows 
  this.x = a*5;
  this.y = 'nothing';
}
```

**Why I am looking for:**

I have  a class with about 15 properties. When I instantiate the class, I have to set all those variable/properties with some default values. So this makes my code heavy as well complex. If I could set some default values to those instance variables from within that class, that must reduce this code complexity/redundancy.

Comment: By 'class variable' do you mean 'instance variable' (ivar)?

Comment: sorry not to mention it clearly. yes its instance variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write *the* init, which is doing all the job of full initialization.

Then just write as many initiators with diferent parameter sets as you need (but think about it: do you really need *this* or *that* one?). No, don’t let them do the job. Do them let fill in all the default values (the ones you don’t provide to the *message*, to *this* message handling implementatino) and give it all to the first one.

This first one initator is called designated initator. **And be sure not to miss [Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3)**
*Never* ignore the designated one!

Greetings

Answer (score 4):

If you don't wanna specify parameters,

```
- (MyClass *)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        a = 4;
        str = @"test";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then when you do `MyClass *instance = [[MyClass alloc] init]`, it'll set the default values for the ivars.

But I don't see why you posted the constructor with parameters but you don't want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

In the class's interface:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger a;
    NSInteger x;
    NSString  *str;
    NSString  *y;
}

- (id)initWithInteger:(NSInteger)someInteger string:(NSString *)someString;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation:

```
- (id)initWithInteger:(NSInteger)someInteger string:(NSString *)someString {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        a = someInteger;
        str = [someString copy];

        x = a * 5;
        y = [@"nothing" retain];
    }

    return self;
}
```

(`NSInteger` is a typedef for `int` or `long`, depending on the architecture.)

Comment: thanks @wevan. still i have to send some params to the initialization method. is there any way to use init{} or something like this without any param?